# Exit animation in Next 13 won't fire using framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I have this simple testimonial slider, where the enter initial works. But the exit animation is totally being ignored. Tried applied mode wait but this doesn't work throws errors. Setting an index as an key, unique ID, title etc etc won't work.

Code:

```
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

import Link from "next/link"

import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion"

import { IconsLibrary } from "@/components/shared"

const ProjectMember = ({ member }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div
      key={member.memberName}
      className="relative text-center"
      onMouseEnter={() => setActive(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setActive(false)}
    >
      <img
        src={member.memberIcon}
        className="w-[68px] h-[68px] object-contain opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 hover:cursor-pointer transition-all ease-in-out duration-500"
      />
      <span
        className={`${
          active ? "-top-8 opacity-100" : "-top-4 opacity-0"
        } transition-all ease-in-out duration-500 bg-mainGreen text-[12px] px-[10px] py-[3px] absolute right-2 rounded-[4px]`}
      >
        {member.memberName}
        <IconsLibrary type="triangle" className="absolute top-[24px] right-[30%]" />
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

const ProjectSidebar = ({ data }) => {
  const [currentTestimonial, setCurrentTestimonial] = useState(0)
  const intervalDuration = 4000
  let intervalId = useRef<number | undefined>()

  const startInterval = () => {
    intervalId.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentTestimonial((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % data.testimonials.length)
    }, intervalDuration)
  }

  const resetInterval = () => {
    if (intervalId.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }
    startInterval()
  }

  const handleNavigation = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentTestimonial(index)
    resetInterval()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    startInterval()

    return () => {
      if (intervalId.current) {
        clearInterval(intervalId.current)
      }
    }
  }, [data.testimonials.length])

  const navArray = Array.from({ length: data.testimonials.length }, (_, index) => {
    return `Element ${index}`
  })
  return (
    <aside className="row-span-2 bg-black rounded-[20px] md:rounded-2xl px-[30px] xl:px-[50px] py-[30px] relative">
      <div className="flex justify-between w-full text-[#a5a5a5] mb-[50px] text-[14px]">
        <span>{data.caseName}</span>
        <span>{data.year}</span>
      </div>

      <div className="flex gap-x-[6px]">
        {data.categories.map((category, index) => (
          <span
            key={index}
            className="rounded-[100px] bg-[#313131] px-[12px] py-[10px] text-sm font-micro-medium leading-none text-white"
          >
            {category}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="my-[30px] relative">
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
          {data.testimonials.map((testimonial, index) => (
            <motion.div
              key={index}
              initial="initialState"
              animate={index === currentTestimonial ? "animateState" : "exitState"}
              exit="exitState"
              transition={{
                type: "tween",
                duration: 0.5
              }}
              variants={{
                initialState: {
                  x: "100vw"
                },
                animateState: {
                  x: 0
                },
                exitState: {
                  x: "-100vw"
                }
              }}
              className={`text-2xl xl:text-3xl xl:leading-8 leading-tight transition-all ease-in-out duration-2000`}
            >
              {currentTestimonial === index ? (
                <p className="text-white font-micro-medium">
                  <span className="text-[#A5A5A5]">{testimonial.authorName}</span>
                  {testimonial.testimonial}
                </p>
              ) : null}
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>

      <div className="flex mt-2">
        {navArray.map((el, index) => (
          <div
            key={el}
            className={`rounded-[100px] transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 h-[6px] mr-[8px] hover:cursor-pointer ${
              index === currentTestimonial ? "w-[20px] bg-white" : "w-[6px] bg-[#737373]"
            }`}
            onClick={() => handleNavigation(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="mt-[40px] flex items-center">
        <Link
          href={data.websiteUrlLink}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          className="relative pl-[14px] text-white font-micro-medium flex items-center gap-x-[10px] text-[22px] underline underline-offset-1 decoration-1 before:block before:absolute before:w-[6px] before:h-[6px] before:rounded-full before:bg-mainGreen before:top-[14px] before:left-0 hover:decoration-mainGreen transition-all ease-linear duration-150"
        >
          {data.websiteUrlText}
          <IconsLibrary type="arrow-square" />
        </Link>
      </div>

      {data.team && (
        <div className="lg:absolute mt-[50px] md:mt-[100px] lg:mt-0 lg:bottom-[50px] left-[50px] flex flex-col">
          <h5 className="text-[#a5a5a5] text-[14px] mb-[22px]">Brainpower behind this project</h5>
          <div className="flex gap-2">
            {data.team.map((member) => (
              <ProjectMember key={member.memberName} member={member} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </aside>
  )
}

export default ProjectSidebar
```